# Show Material UI chip on click of menu item

Tags: reactjs, arrays, sorting, material-ui, categories

Sorry I don't know why the indentation on this code is so off. I want to show a chip every time a menu item is clicked, but with this current code it is showing a chip with all of the categories lumped together (ie "category 1category 2category 3" instead of "category 1". How can I set this up so that when Category 1 is clicked just the "Category 1" chip shows up, and when Category 2 is clicked just the "Category 2" chip shows up. Thanks.

```
        const categories = [
          'Category 1',
          'Category 2',
          'Category 3',
        ];
            
export default function Test() {
  const [selectedCategory, setSelectedCategory] = React.useState(null);
  const [anchorEl, setAnchorEl] = React.useState(null);
  const open = Boolean(anchorEl);
  const handleClick = (event) => {
    setAnchorEl(event.currentTarget);
  };
  const handleClose = () => {
    setAnchorEl(null);
  };

  const [expanded, setExpanded] = React.useState(false)
  const handleExpandClick = () => setExpanded(!expanded)

  const [showChip, setShowChip] = useState(false);

  const handleCategoryClick = () => {
    setShowChip(true);
    setSelectedCategory(categories);
    setAnchorEl(null);
  };

            
            return (
                              <Button
                                id="basic-button"
                                aria-controls={open ? 'basic-menu' : undefined}
                                aria-haspopup="true"
                                aria-expanded={open ? 'true' : undefined}
                                onClick={handleClick}
                              >
                                Categories
                              </Button>
                              <Menu
                                id="basic-menu"
                                anchorEl={anchorEl}
                                open={open}
                                onClose={handleClose}
                                MenuListProps={{
                                  'aria-labelledby': 'basic-button',
                                }}
                                
                              >
                                {categories.map((categories) => (
                                  <MenuItem
                                    key={categories}
                                    value={categories}
                                    onClick={handleClick}
                                  >
                                    {categories}
                                  </MenuItem>
                                ))}
        {selectedCategory && <Chip key={selectedCategory} label={selectedCategory} />}
                              </Menu>
            );
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure if I fully understand the desired result due to posted code seems partial, but if the goal is:

> when Category 1 is clicked just the "Category 1" chip shows up, and when Category 2 is clicked just the "Category 2" chip shows up

Perhaps try have `MenuItem` pass the needed value to the handler `handleCategoryClick`:

```
  categories.map((categories) => (
    <MenuItem
      key={categories}
      value={categories}
      onClick={() => handleCategoryClick(categories)}
    >
      {categories}
    </MenuItem>
  ));
```

In `handleCategoryClick` receive and set the related state with the clicked value:

```
  const handleCategoryClick = (categories) => {
    setShowChip(true);
    setSelectedCategory(categories);
    setAnchorEl(null);
  };
```

Because `Chip` is already displayed conditionally and has wired up `label` with the state, it should display the right value when state `selectedCategory` is updated.

```
  selectedCategory && (
    <Chip
      key={selectedCategory}
      label={selectedCategory}
    />
  );
```

Comment: THANK YOU that did the trick! Problem I'm facing now is that the chips aren't stacking, when I click another category it replaces the last one and only one chip is ever visible.